# HTMLCollection retorna undefined quando acesso seus elementos

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, console

Tenho esse código no meu script:

```html
const navLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
console.log(navLinks)
```

Ele me retorna isso no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando tento acessar os elementos de navLinks (esse é o meu objetivo em um laço for):

```html
const navLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
console.log('Elemento 0: ', navLinks[0])
```

Ele me retorna undefined:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, e isso é o mais curioso e irritante, quando eu acesso os elementos de 'navLinks', pelo console, funciona corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha dúvida é: como e por que isso ocorre? **

Comment: Cara, tem alguma coisa estranha, copiei o seu código e funcionou: https://jsfiddle.net/jguedx4m/

Comment: Dúvida 1, você está utilizando JQuery?
Dúvida 2 você está fazendo esse teste depois que todo o DOM é carregado?
_Se eu pegar exatamente seu código sem o restante do contexto, vai funcionar normalmente_
Portanto deve-se atentar quando você está executando essa ação. Pois os elementos podem não terem sido carregados/criados, no momento da chamada.
Talvez seria interessante nos passar mais detalhes, ou testar em outro trecho do código...
Seu teste funciona no console, pois o DOM está completamente carregado

Comment: Nossa! Muito obrigado, cara. Vamos lá, dúvida 1: Não, eu não estou utilizando jQuery. Dúvida 2: realmente, o problema estava no carregamento dos elementos no DOM, como vc sinalizou. Não tinha percebido esse detalhe. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.